# input text validate react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've got the following code:

```
 <TextInput placeholder={"PID"}  keyboardType = 'numeric'  editable = {true}    maxLength = {10} value={this.state.text}  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})} />   
 <Button title='NEXT' onPress= {() => navigate('service', { text: this.state.text})}> </Button>
```

And I want to validate the input field like this:
On a press of the button go to the service page if the length of input is equal to 10. 
Else show an alert message.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
manage = () => {
    if (this.state.text.length === 10) {
        navigate('service', { text: this.state.text})})
    } else {
        alert('Your PID must be exactly 10 characters!')
    }
}

render() {
    return (<Button onPress={this.manage} ... />)
}
```

Comment: It's @sod.heretic's answer, I just helped with the formatting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Dear :) You need to use a routing package, like react-navigation or react-native-router-flux (I like the later), define your pages with it, and use a simple if else statement in the onPress function...

Each of the routing packages provide a simple call for programmatic navigation.